# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "show": syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am building a table in `pyqt5` which will show the output of `SQL` in the table. First you have to type the command in command line and then press the button to update the table.

Although, the commands like `insert into table` are working but when i type `show databases;` in the command line it is showing me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/intel/Desktop/table.py", line 24, in load_data
    result = connection.execute(inp)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "show": syntax error
```

**Here is my code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sqlite3

inp = input('>> ')

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 table - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()
#CREATE TABLE employees(email varchar(30), password(30));
    def load_data(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect('my_db.db')
        #connection.execute(inp)
        #
        result = connection.execute(inp)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)

        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))

        connection.close()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.createTable()

        # Add box layout, add table to box layout and add box layout to widget
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget) 
        self.setLayout(self.layout) 

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.move(100,600)
        self.btn.setText("Hello")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.load_data)
        # Show widget
        self.show()

    def createTable(self):

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1) ##set number of rows 
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(8) ##this is fixed for myTableWidget, ensure that both of your tables, sql and qtablewidged have the same number of columns 


        self.tableWidget.move(1,1)

        # table selection change
        self.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        print("\n")
        for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
            print(currentQTableWidgetItem.row(), currentQTableWidgetItem.column(), currentQTableWidgetItem.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Any help would be appreciated!!**

Comment: There is no SQL command "show" (at least not supported by sqlite).

Comment: Yes there is in MySQL @MichaelButscher I don't know why it's happening in SQLite3??

Comment: SQL is not perfectly standardized. Each DB software has its own dialect.

Comment: Okay, so should i use SQLAlchemy ?? will it support the same mysql commands??

Comment: OR any library suggestion??

Comment: On SQLite `show databases` does not even make sense. Since there is only one database in one database file.

Comment: @AbhaySalvi it looks to me that you're having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to use the command "show databases"? It doesn't even appear on your code. Is there a reason for using "user typed" commands? Also, you should avoid using names like [`width`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#width-prop), [`height`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#height-prop) or [`layout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layout) on QWidget, as they are part of the standard QWidget class attribute/property names.

Comment: [SQL As Understood By Sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `show databases` command in SQLite because there is typically only the one. However, there is `PRAGMA database_list` [database_list](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_database_list). This will list the main database and any attached databases *(as attached using `ATTACH DATABASE 'path_to_the_database' the_schema`)* [ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html).

e.g. `PRAGMA database_list;` :-

```
seq name    file
0   main    E:\Navicat\SQlite Databases\soanswers.db
2   sw      E:\Navicat\SQlite Databases\xxx.db
```

- name is the schema name used when attaching the database.

Otherwise, it would be a case of searching through the file system or part of it, perhaps checking the first 16 bytes of the file for "SQLite format 3\000" [database_header](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#the_database_header) if you wanted to find SQLite database files.

Comment: How to view number of tables in it then? I used `.tables` command but it's showing me `syntax error near "."` @Mike T

Comment: @AbhaySalvi query sqlite_master as per [(7) How do I list all tables/indices contained in an SQLite database](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7)